# Filtering by the entity an EVA field is attached to

Tags: 8, views

I've got a very nested set of entity reference relationships, and they're all nodes/content types, but each is a different bundle/type. It's something like:

- There's a field on Content Type A that points to a Content Type B
- There's a field on Content Type B that points to a Content Type C
- There's a field on Content Type C that points to a Content Type D

When displaying Content Type D, I want to sort of go backwards and each one higher up is display nested in the one that it points to. So, something like:

```
Content Type D stuff
_______________________________
| Content Type C stuff        |
| ____________________________|
| | Content Type B stuff      |
| | __________________________|
| | | Content Type A stuff    | 
|_|_|_________________________|
```

Now, there can be many As, Bs and Cs, above is just the simplest. So, something like:

```
Content Type D stuff
_______________________________
| Content Type C stuff        |
| ____________________________|
| | Content Type B stuff      |
| | __________________________|
| | | Content Type A stuff    | 
|_|_|_________________________|
| Content Type C stuff        |
| ____________________________|
| | Content Type B stuff      |
| |___________________________|
| | Content Type B stuff      |
| | __________________________|
| | | Content Type A stuff    |  
|_|_|_________________________|
```

I thought of doing this:

- D's display will just be the normal node page. Great.
- I create a Views block that shows up on D nodes, and does a contextual filter by URL, showing C types as rendered entities. Great.
- I created an EVA field, and attached it to C types, that displays B types.... and here's where I hit the problem.

I can traverse my way up through the relationships, and filter by URL like I did with the block view, but that means that every C that the block view displays will display EVERY B that's associated with that D, not just the ones with that particular B->C relationship. I have no idea how to do this.

Is there any way, presumably with the contextual filter, to get the entity information for the entity that the EVA field is attached to?

(If you're wondering why these relationships were built this way, it was a D6->D8 migration, and it was just decided that this would be the quickest path. Please, I'm hoping for a view solution if it exists.)